# Magento2 : Cron script readiness check failed

Tags: crontab, magento2.2.4, magento-cron

I am trying to install the extensions and I am getting following errors. I have already set the crontab as well.

Check Cron Scripts

Cron script readiness check failed. Hide detail

Error from Updater Application Cron Script:

**Found non-writable path(s):**

/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Analytics/Controller
/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Analytics/Controller/Adminhtml
/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Analytics/Controller/Adminhtml/Reports
/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Analytics/Controller/Adminhtml/Reports/Show
/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Analytics/Controller/Adminhtml/Reports/Show/Interceptor.php

For additional assistance, see cron scripts help.
[image]

How can be solved this?

Comment: give permission for the generated folder...

Comment: @JeevaChezhiyan I have already given the permission -> drwxrwxrwx  4 root root